# Discord.js can't use "send" function to DM a person because it is undefined?

Tags: javascript

I'm new from discord.js and I had recently meet some problem here. I can't use  "send" function to DM a person because it is undefined. This is how my thing looks like

```
const user = client.users.cache.get('KillerHK#3150');
 user.send('hello there');
```

It shows up `TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined`.
Yes I have that

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
```

event handler thingy

Comment: What version of discord.js are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you tried to .get a user, it can only accept an ID, not the username & tag. Try using

> `client.users.cache.get('your id, for example 2983190921391')`.

Comment: #2 is wrong. `.get()` operates on the (sync) cache. `client.users.fetch('id')` DOES need await however.